# how to initialize the built in django development server on OSX 10.7 (lion)

Tags: django, django-admin

when running

> **$ django-admin.py runserver**

I get:
(in red letters)

> **Error: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is          undefined.**

in previous versions (python 2.5, django 1.2) I never had this problem.
Ive tried setting the setting module manually then it tells me to put it on sys.path. once I set the sys path in bash using the python interpreter I close it and it dissappears from the sys.path? Im using OSX 10.7's Apache 2.2.19 and python 2.7.1 build right out of the box. Running out of ideas. Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually figured it out. for anyone else that has become as forgetful as I, you have to pass those variable to the shell by adding python to the front of it.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

without the python in front of it the shell doesn't know where to send it.

Answer (score 4):

Why do people keep trying to run the devserver with `django-admin.py`? Where is this documented?

The correct way to do it is with **`manage.py`**.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port ... The experience Djangoer knows that manage.py is basically a wrapper for django-admin.py that includes the project settings, so you should actually use manage.py instead, but I could see how the newbie user would be confused by the docs. Some clarification should probably be added to the documentation.

Comment: Well, actually the docs do state that you should substitute manage.py for django-admin.py in many cases, but they do so in a brief sentence or two at the very top. Most people looking for a particular management command probably never see this. I didn't at first either.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use django-admin.py to start the devserver if you have a more custom setup (i.e. a settings file that isn't called settings.py or you have multiple settings files and want to switch between them).

When you use django-admin.py you have to give it two extra command line arguments so that it knows where your project is and what settings file to use.

For example:

Your project exists in: `/path/to/myproject`

Settings file: `/path/to/myproject/site1.py`

```
django-admin.py runserver --pythonpath=/path/to/myproject --settings=site1
```